# Determining RHEL Type (Workstation vs Server)

Tags: rhel, version

How do I tell whether or not I have Red Hat Server or Workstation? I know my redhat release info is in /etc/redhat-release.

`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.9 (Tikanga)`

I need to order an updated subscription, but do not  know whether to ask for Workstation 5.

Comment: server `/etc/redhat-release` would say : `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell by looking at /etc/redhat-release. Here is how they look like on each system:

```
 Workstation:
 /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.2 Beta

 Client:
 /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.9 (Tikanga)

 Server:
 /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: So I renew the subscription based on client then. That's what you're saying.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer applies to newer RHEL releases. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654324/determining-rhel-type-workstation-vs-server-for-rhel8) for RHEL8.

Answer (score 0):

You are running Workstation, Server release says "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server in `/etc/redhat-release`.

```
[root@archiware ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

You can also try running `rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release`.

```
[root@archiware ~]# rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release
redhat-release-server-6Server-6.5.0.1.el6.x86_64
```