# Determining RHEL Type (Workstation vs Server) for RHEL8

Tags: rhel

I have a rhel deployed as a VM and want to determine if it is a Server or Workstation. The command

I am running the following commands to find out:

```
$ cat /etc/rhel-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)

$ rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release
redhat-release-8.2-1.0.el8.x86_64

$ uname -as
Linux opus-c-master 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 14:35:58 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

None of these commands telling me the type.

Can anyone able to help?

Comment: That does not work for newer versions like RHEL8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On RHEL 8, you can use `syspurpose` to determine the configured purpose of a system, *e.g.*

```
$ sudo syspurpose show
{
  "role": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation",
  "usage": "Production"
}
```

Configuring this is, however, optional. To configure a system’s purpose, run

```
sudo syspurpose --set-role="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
```

(the role can be [one of “Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server”, “Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation”, “Red Hat Enterprise Linux Compute Node”](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/configuring-system-purpose-advanced_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user)).

If you’re interested in the subscription type that’s used on the system, run

```
sudo subscription-manager list --consumed | grep "Roles:"
```

This will indicate the role of the system as subscribed.

Comment: sudo syspurpose show is empty: {}. How to configure this? I do not want the subscription type but the type of RHEL I have installed.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks but this is like we are telling it what role we want it to play. I may set up anything I want? One distribution cannot be workstation and server at the same time I guess. What I am interested to know the type of distribution installed. In the previous versions, you could get this info from /etc/redhat-release: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146174/determining-rhel-type-workstation-vs-server

Comment: The base system in RHEL 8 is the same in all roles. The role changes the subscriptions that are attached automatically to the system, but it’s only a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subscription-manager list --consumed` to view the subscription attached to your system. In the output of this command you will have a line starting with *Subscription Name:*. This line will tell you what kind of subscription you system is using. This is however not a guarantee that you system is indeed of the type indicated by the subscription.